# Difference between "durchaus" and "völlig"

Tags: word-usage, difference, word-choice

From what I read in Duden, Wictionary, and others, it looks like *durchaus* and *völlig* can be used as synonyms in most cases, but not always. It looks like *völlig* can always be replaced by *durchaus*, but not the other way round.

Therefore, what are the cases / contexts in which *durchaus* cannot be replaced by *völlig*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all the formal difference: While *durchaus* is an adverb (built from the concatenation of two prepositions), *völlig* is an adjective. From a formal viewpoint that means *völlig* can be replaced by *durchaus* when in adverbial use only (for example, when *völlig* modifies another adjective as in the following example).

> Das ist völlig richtig

> Das ist durchaus richtig

Note, however, the replacement modifies the meaning - The second example expects an "aber" (like in most cases when *durchaus* is used), while the first one doesn't necessarily.

When used as an adjective, the replacement doesn't really work:

> Das ist völliger Blödsinn

> Das ist durchaus Blödsinn ...

(The "durchaus" example is a valid sentence, but the meaning is entirely different: "völliger Blödsinn" is "complete nonsense", but the second example translates to something along the lines of )

> While this may be nonsense, .....

I would rather state that *sometimes* (but, in most cases, not) *durchaus* and *völlig* **can** be synonyms.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 3):

They don't really mean the same thing at all.

"durchaus" = "indeed"

"völlig" = "completely"

That is, "völlig" (cognate with "fully") strengthens the part it modifies, it emphasizes that it is truly completely so.

"durchaus" is mainly for expressing contrasts with some other (expressed or implied) idea.

I did some web searching for practical uses of "durchaus" and found these:

- [Träumen ist bei den Gießen 46ers durchaus erlaubt](https://www.mittelhessen.de/sport/basketball/basketball-wetzlar/traeumen-ist-bei-den-giessen-46ers-durchaus-erlaubt-3226640) (i.e. dreaming is allowed, in contrast to what some might think; wouldn't mean the same thing at all with "völlig")
- [Wenn ich beispielsweise den Regierungsvorschlag für die Besetzung des EU-Kommissars in der laufenden Legislaturperiode machen muss, dann finde ich das durchaus richtig, dass man nicht ohne vereinbarten Modus einfach abwartet.](https://www.derstandard.at/story/2000132949524/ex-vizekanzler-mitterlehner-sideletter-sind-durchaus-uebliche-spielregel) (he finds it right in contrast to what someone else might think; with "völlig" it would mean he finds it completely right)
- [Dabei ist die vorzeitige Übergabe der königlichen Amtsgeschäfte durchaus populär geworden.](https://www.rtl.de/cms/koenig-harald-von-norwegen-dementiert-abdankungsgeruechte-5074413.html) (it has become popular in contrast to expectations; "völlig populär" is not a natural expression)

Comment: That is an interesting and unusual comparison, thanks for pointing that direction out!